# Is there any difference between the phrases "text representation" and "text feature representation"?

Tags: natural-language-processing, terminology, definitions, vector-semantics

Text representation, in simple words, is representing text in sensible numeric form. You can read in detail [from](https://link.springer.com/referenceworkentry/10.1007%2F978-0-387-39940-9_420) the following paragraph

> Text representation is one of the fundamental problems in text mining
> and Information Retrieval (IR). It aims to **numerically represent the
> unstructured text documents to make them mathematically computable**.
> For a given set of text documents $D = \{d_i, i=1, 2,...,n\}$, where
> each $d_i$ stands for a document, the problem of text representation
> is to represent each $d_i$ of $D$ as a point $s_i$ in a numerical space
> $S$, where the distance/similarity between each pair of points in
> space $S$ is well defined.

But, I came across the phrase "text feature representation" in research papers. Features, in general, are [present in dataset](https://ai.stackexchange.com/questions/30378/can-i-always-interpret-features-as-random-variables-in-machine-learning-safely). But, I think, features can be characters or words or documents or complete text (as a single feature?) in the case of the text. I am not sure about what we call features in the text.

So, I am not sure about what is meant by **text feature representation**. Is it the same as text representation?

Answer (score 1):

I think that literature is simply inconsistent in this regard. But here's a distinction that I think helps to shade a bit of light on this question:

***text representation***: as you said we have to convert text into numerical variables. This term refers to general strategies to convert text into numbers, like embedding, bag of words, and so on.

***text features representation***: this is **what we feed to a real model**. The difference is that it can be a combination of different text representation. For example, I could apply a TF-IDF vectorizer to a corpus and use it to encode each word of a sentence and then use also pre-trained embedding to encode the same sentence/document, concatenating for each word both vectors. Or another commonly used strategy is to use multiple n-grams, which also consist in applying multiple text representations to the same sentence/document.

Comment: I feel that **what we fed to a real model** is the key point...

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I edited the answer to stress that